# Joining Two Dataframes in Pandas With Different Column Names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes one displaying the transactions from a checking account and the other displaying transactions on a credit card. The only difference between the two lists is that the former seperates the transactions into 'debit' and 'credit' transactions and the latter only has the credit usage, a negative number indicating cashback and non-negative a normal purchase on the card. I would like to 'join', if you will, these two while appending the transactions with negative numbers to the credit side of the first list and the non-negative ones to the debit side. Besides those two columns there is a 'TransactionID' column that is has the same purpose for both lists. Here is a bit of the lists:

df0:

```
                                         TransactionID    Debit   Credit
0    HCCLAIMPMT BCBS TEXAS TRN*1*C20120E10592180*13...     0.00    21.29
1                    BANKCARD BTOT DEP 543052900022658     0.00   124.93
2                                          Check #1867  8755.50     0.00
```

df1:

```
    Amount                    TransactionID
0    -3.41    YOUR CASH BACK THIS PERIOD IS
1    29.22              PAYPAL ON EBAY MARK
2    30.45                     REDTAGFABRIC
```

How do I go about joining them?

EDIT- Expected output:

```
                                      TransactionID       Debit   Credit
0    HCCLAIMPMT BCBS TEXAS TRN*1*C20120E10592180*13...     0.00    21.29
1                    BANKCARD BTOT DEP 543052900022658     0.00   124.93
2                                          Check #1867  8755.50     0.00
0                        YOUR CASH BACK THIS PERIOD IS     0.00     3.41
1                                  PAYPAL ON EBAY MARK    29.22     0.00      
2                                         REDTAGFABRIC    30.45     0.00
```

Comment: Please post your exact expected output based on the sample of dataframes you posted.

Comment: Just rename the columns and use `concat` or `join` or `merge` also are they lists or dataframes? both very different things.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I did so although it was explained and but now illustrated.

Comment: @Datanovice I have versions of the data in lists and dataframes but yes the ones I showed here are dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to me you want to **join** as in SQL join, but concat the two dataframes. To do so, notice that one of your debit or credit is zero. You can consider this:

```
# assume df2 is the List2 dataframe, add "debit" and "credit" columns
df2['Debit'] = df2['Amount'].clip(0)
df2['Credit'] = (-df2['Amont']).clip(0)

# combine them
combined = pd.concat([df1, df2[['TransactionID', 'Debit', 'Credit']]])
```

Comment: I am receiving error- "TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int" on the first line in the code. None of the data are Integers however so I don't understand the error. Do they have to be converted into floats or integers for '.clip()' to work?

Comment: That means your Amount column is in string format. Try replace all `df['Amount']` to `df['Amount'].astype(float)`